# How can I fire something after $(document).ready() completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Is there a way to have your function be called as the LAST in the `$(document).ready()` queue or, is there a way to trigger an event once this has completed?

I want to essentially see if something was fired by `$(document).ready()` and, if not, fire it after wards.  If I put this code into document ready then there is no guarantee it will execute last so could result in multiple checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another `$(document).ready()` block to the end of your code.  jQuery executes them in the order it sees them, so if you put another block at the end of the code, it should be called after the other finishes.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a global variable when your function is fired, and check that before running it again:

E.g.,

```
function myFunc()
{
    if (myFuncHasFired)
        return;
    myFuncHasFired = true;
    //your func code here
}
```

This does not guarantee your function will run last, but satisfies what I think is your real requirement that the function not run multiple times in one request.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect use case for the readyX plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/readyx

The plugin provides a queue for ready events that should happen last.